# Login with the second table data

Tags: laravel

Can someone help me how to login with the student_id that is linked to the second table. For example; second table have id like 'abc', so i want to login as 'abc' and when it post to the next page, it will retrieve data that links to 'abc' data only not all data.

AuthController.php

```
public function getLogin()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}

public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    if($this->auth->attempt($request->only('student_id', 'password')))
    {
        return redirect('/student/profile');
    }

    return redirect('/auth/login')
        ->withErrors([
            'student_id'=>'Invalid User ID'
        ]);
}
```

route.php

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return View::make('auth/login');
});

Route::get('student/profile', 
    ['middleware' => 'auth','uses' =>'Auth\AuthController@postLogin']);

Route::post('/student/profile',array(
    'as'=>'login',
    'uses'=>'StudentController@getProfile'
));
```

login.blade.php

```
<section id="container">
    {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin')) !!}
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <p>Student ID : {!! Form::text('student_id',null)!!}</p>
    <p>Password : {!! Form::password('password')!!}</p>

    <p>{!! Form::submit('Login') !!} </p>
    {!! Form::close()!!}
</section>
```

Comment: can you elaborate your question a little more

Comment: when i login as id: abc, pword: abc. it will move to the next page named profile. in the profile table, there are many data that have different id. so, i just want data that link to the id: abc. when i login as 'try', i just want retrieve data profile that have id 'try' in the table profile.. here, there are two tables named user(for login) and profile (for display data).

Comment: After a user is successfully logged in you can get the user details with `Auth::user();` so you can use this to retrieve `id` of the logged in user and then retrieve profile information using this `id` using `with`.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes are not correct (not logical).

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    // when user is already login
    if (Auth::user()) {
        return redirect('students/profile');
    }

    return redirect('login');
});

Route::get('login', ['uses' =>'Auth\AuthController@getLogin']);
Route::post('login', ['as' => 'login','uses' =>'Auth\AuthController@postLogin']);
Route::post('student/profile',['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses'=>'StudentController@getProfile' ]);
```

After a student is login the `getProfile` controller method could look like:

```
public function getProfile() {
    // get data from user thats login
    $user = Auth::user();

    $userData = ModelForTableTwo::where('student_id', $user->id)->get();

    // more stuff

    return View::make('path.to.view', compact('userData', 'user'));
}
```

Comment: Because there is a check if a user is login and when a user is login redirect to the profile page from the student

Comment: i got variable id: undefined.

Comment: You have still an session running? Do you even login properly?

Comment: for the 1st time i ran, it displayed login page. when i clicked login, page student/profile displayed 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:' and when i refresh http://localhost:8000/ again, it directly go to path, student/profile. why ?

Comment: i understood right now. this is because there is no logout right? its running for login until switch it to logout. the displayed data only from the user id even there are many user id in the table. its work.. thank u for ur sharing.. =)

Comment: By default (without remembering) a session expires within 15 minutes I thought. In this case; yes until your logout the `Auth::user()` should contain the login user information.

Did you solve your problem?